# How Many 3 letter words from characters in "ABRACADABRA"?

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

The words cannot have a repetition of letters and each character of the type is distinct i.e. the first 'B' is distinct from the second 'B', and both the 'B's can not be in a word simultaneously.

I need an algorithm/formula that answers for any word(provided as count of each letter).

for a smaller word: **AABBC**
answers are permutations of these letters:

1. A1B1C
2. A1B2C
3. A2B1C
4. A2B2C

These are all the combinations.

So count of all words is = 4 * 3P3 = 4 * 6 = 24

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please read this text about [how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question).

Comment: should these be words found in a dictionary, or any combination of three characters "words"?

Comment: any combination

Comment: You don't have to worry about A1, B1 vs A2, B2. Once you've assigned the numbers to the characters 0-9 then they are unique.

Comment: In true math exchange style I don't see why this question is closed. This is a perfectly valid question.

Comment: I got my answer :)

Answer (score 1):

In your question, the total number of 3 letter groupings which do not repeat a letter will be

{11 /choose 3} - {5/choose2}x(11-3) - {2/choose2}x(11-2) = G (say)

where the second term takes care of excluding the words having atleast 2 A’s and the third term for words having atleast 2 B’s.
So, the total words will be G x 3!

You can follow a similar procedure for any word, wherein you’ll have to subtract a term for each repeated letter.

Comment: wrong answer for (A: 8, B: 1, C: 8). Expected ans = 64

Comment: I just got it: It should not be (11 - 2) there. You're repeating cases like A1A2-A3, A1A3-A2, A2A3-A1.

Comment: Yes, you’re right, it’s my bad. Replace (11-2) with (11-3) to fix that.

Comment: it's still not correct. but it helped me to get the correct answer. thanks for answering

ans = 11C3 - (5C2 * (11-5) + 5C3) - 2C2 - 2C2 = 88

You should fix your answer

Answer (score 1):

As an algorithm:

```
loop over (0-9) as A   
  loop over (0-9 excluding A) as B
    loop over(0-9 excluding B) as C
      output ABC
    end
  end
end
```

You could try asking this question on stackoverflow as well.

Comment: actually i need only the count of the words. I implemented this here in findans() accepting count of different characters: https://www.codechef.com/viewsolution/29776763. need someting better

Comment: I wrote an (n ^ 2) solution: https://www.codechef.com/viewsolution/29788903. I was wondering if anything better is possible?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/dataphile/vcn70quo/2/